# Как отключить показ системных скриптов при отладке в PhPStorm?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, phpstorm

[image: Что я вижу при отладке.]

Собственно я заходил в настройки этой IDE там где stepping пробовал вручную прописывать имена этих файлов чтобы при отладке их обходило, но почему-то они всё равно открываются, я хочу видеть только то что происходит в моих файлах, чтобы мне не показывало что там в системных или служебных скриптах, но почему-то избежать их показа мне не удаётся.
Может кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой и знает как её решить?

Например если выполнять скрипт по шагам в Chrome то такого не происходит.
Я же не нажимаю кнопку "Force step into" которая по идее не смотря на черный список должна входить в файлы которые игнорируются, я нажимаю либо "step over" либо "step into" в зависимости от того что мне надо посмотреть.

Comment: Погорячился, в Chrome тоже показываются эти файлы в которые мне не хотелось бы входить.

Answer (score 0):

**Стало быть, спустя время я удалил Jetbrains IDE расширение с Google Chrome, которое как бы для отладки нужно, и стал отлаживать без него. После этого у меня всё ненужное перестало отображаться.**